# Random effects in Bayesian network or Decision Tree

Tags: random-effects-model, bayes, decision-theory

I wonder if we can incorporate a random effect model (as it is used a function..for example linear or logistic regression) to other machine learning algorithms such as Bayes network or decision tree?

Is there any academic work which has been done in this regard?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For regression trees, there is some recent work that allows to include random intercepts, especially for dealing with clustered data. See e.g.:

- Hajjem A, Bellavance F, Larocque D (2011). "Mixed Effects Regression
  Trees for Clustered Data." *Statistics & Probability Letters*, **81**(4), 451-459.
- Sela R, Simonoff J (2012). "RE-EM Trees: A Data Mining Approach for
  Longitudinal and Clustered Data." *Machine Learning*, **86**(2), 169-207.